# BackgroundTasks not changing values when activated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to use the BackgroundTask framework to run a block of code periodically when the user closes the app. Preferably, I would want the code to run once every hour. In the project file below, I have the code change a value stored in UserDefaults, but no matter how long I wait it never runs the code in the task.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import BackgroundTasks
import OSLog

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.refresh", using: nil) { task in
            Logger().info("[BGTASK] Preform bg fetch \("com.example.refresh")")
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
            self.scheduleAppRefresh()
        }
        
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.restock", using: nil) { task in
            Logger().info("[BGTASK] Preform bg fetch \("com.example.restock")")
            AppUserDefaults.newString = "New String" // <-- The string is changed here
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
            self.scheduleBackgroundProcessing()
        }
        
        return true
    }

    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.refresh")

        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)

        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh task \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func scheduleBackgroundProcessing() {
        let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.restock")
        request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true
        request.requiresExternalPower = false

        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1 * 60)

        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule image fetch: (error)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Logger().info("App did enter background")
        self.scheduleAppRefresh()
        self.scheduleBackgroundProcessing()
    }
}
```

When the app loads, I show ***newString*** in the ContentView:

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("New String: \(AppUserDefaults.newString)")
    }
}
```

[Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBDGAzGIp0kS-3RBRDjEpeJowKnawUEr/view?usp=sharing)